# Pulling PDF email attachment fields into Salesforce fields using Email Services

Tags: apex-email-service

I am currently using Email Services as a way to have a customer's email update certain fields in a record relative to them (based on a customer ID# which is included in the subject of the email).

Their emails contain a pdf attachment. I would like to strip the value out of the fields on the pdf document and populate certain fields in their Salesforce record.

Is that possible ? Has anybody ever done it ?

Comment: It doesn't seem very feasible.  Here's a previous questions/answer  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82972/reading-a-pdf-file-in-apex-controller

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Apex by default.

Your most viable solution would be to grab the PDF and send it over to some other server to do the processing for you, and return the values you want. This requires a callout and might require quite some bandwidth if the PDFs are large.